# Ubuntu 12.04 Gnome 3 "freezes" randomly - not a normal freeze though

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, gnome3, mouse, freeze

Since upgrading to 12.04, I've randomly experienced this strange phenomenon where my mouse mostly doesn't work and keyboard mostly does. I have not been able to identify a cause for this. Sometimes it will happen minutes after I start-up, other times after the computer has been idle for a while, and other times in the middle of working on something. It lasts until I reboot the computer or restart Gnome.

The mouse won't be able to interact with any open windows, but if I do ALT+Tab, I can't keyboard nav through those, I can only click to change windows that way. Same if I press the Windows key; the keyboard remains focused in whatever window was just active but I can click things with my mouse to open new programs.

Anyone else experienced this? What might be causing it? Is there a fix?

Comment: I have seen such behaviour with wireless mice with low battery... try another mouse?

Comment: I have a wired mouse and am plugged in. :-/

Comment: Get a different mouse and try it.  I think your mouse might be having an issue.  Another thing to try is to change the USB port being used, this has sometimes worked.

Comment: I'll give that a try, but I believe I have experienced this with the mouse plugged into several different USB ports.

Comment: Check `dmesg` and `/var/log/messages` after the freeze happens.  If you see anything interesting, update your question with that information, or paste the whole thing in a [pastebin](http://pastebin.com)

Comment: Since I started using a different mouse, I haven't experienced it again. @vonbrand, if you put that as an answer and I still haven't seen the problem by tomorrow, I'll accept it and award you the bounty.

Comment: It started happening again. With the new mouse. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen such behaviour with wireless mice with low battery... try another mouse?

Failing USB mice can also behave erratically, in my experience.

Answer (score 2):

To help debug, you can try reading the raw mouse events from `/dev/input/mice`.  This python script, from [johnroach.info](http://johnroach.info/2011/02/16/getting-raw-data-from-a-usb-mouse-in-linux-using-python/), can help interpret the raw data.  I've modified it slightly below:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python

mouse = file('/dev/input/mice')  
while True:  
    status, dx, dy = tuple(ord(c) for c in mouse.read(3))  

    def to_signed(n):  
        return n - ((0x80 & n) << 1)  

    dx = to_signed(dx)  
    dy = to_signed(dy)  
    print "%#02x %d %d" % (status, dx, dy)
```

The next time your computer "freezes", run this script as root.  It will print out x and y values for the *change* in the mouse position as input on your USB port.  If these values correspond to what the pointer does on the screen, then it is likely you have a problem with your USB ports, motherboard, or a driver.  If these values correspond to what the physical mouse is doing, then the problem is somewhere in the software.

Answer (score 1):

Try to get a terminal by pressing Alt, Ctrl, F2 buttons together (F3 to F6 should also work).  After logging in, check /var/log/messages, /var/log/dmesg etc as USB errors are logged there. It will help to find out the reason.